# create_app(test_config=None) works even though it is not called

Tags: python, flask

I am following flask official tutorial in [The Application Factory](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/)

First create a app dir

```
mkdir flaskr
```

and init it

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

Then run the app as

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

It works but very strange to me

```
* Serving Flask app "flaskr"
* Environment: development
* Debug mode: on
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 855-212-761
```

In `create_app` is defined in `__init__` but has not been applied or invoked.

Even though, the "hello app" is produced.

just cannot wrap mind around it, could you please provide any hints?

Comment: See https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/cli.py#L52. The function *has* been invoked.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @jonrsharpe